# Do ternary evaluations need to be parameterized?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

It seems that if I put code in my ternary evaluation it fails, but placing `true` or `false` it works.

Here is my code:

```
>test = [nil]
=> [nil]

>test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"
SyntaxError: (irb):16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"
                  ^
(irb):16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"

>test.any? ? true : false
=> false

>test << 1
=> [nil, 1]

>test.any? ? true : false
=> true


>test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"
SyntaxError: (irb):14: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"
                  ^
(irb):14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
test.any? ? puts "AAA" : puts "BBB"
                        ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses.

```
>> test.any? ? puts("AAA") : puts("BBB")
BBB
=> nil
```

You should avoid parentheseless call in inline functions.

Comment: Thanks.  The example above now works but the line of code that starting this issue is as follows (I just added the parens), but still seems to not be very happy `@selected_ratings.any? ? (Movie.where(:rating => @selected_ratings.keys)) : (@movies = Movie.all)`  Any thoughts on a more complex ternary?

Comment: Maybe you could show the error too? But I don't think the problem is in the ternary method anymore.

Comment: I just got it, the first option did not have a `@movies = ` like the second option.  Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur maybe the best would be to write `@movies = @selected_ratings.any? ? Movie.where(:rating => @selected_ratings.keys) : Movie.all`

Comment: Once I figured out that was my issue that is exactly what I did.  Noob mistakes :]